# Selecting features within specified number of attribute groups closest to point using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, select

I have a table of subway stops in NYC and what I am trying to do is select the points from the five closest subway stops to a given point. However, each subway 'stop' has multiple points associated with it due to there being many entrances for each stop.

The table looks like this:

| ogc_fid | line | name | objectid | url | wkb_geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2-5 | Birchall Ave & Sagamore St at NW corner | 1734.0 | http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/ | POINT (-73.86835600032798 |
| 2 | 2-5 | Birchall Ave & Sagamore St at NE corner | 1735.0 | http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/ | POINT (-73.86821300022677 |
| 3 | 2-5 | Morris Park Ave & 180th St at NW corner | 1736.0 | http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/ | POINT (-73.87349900050798 |
| 4 | 2-5 | Morris Park Ave & 180th St at NW corner | 1737.0 | http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/ | POINT (-73.8728919997833 |
| 5 | 2-5 | Boston Rd & 178th St at SW corner | 1738.0 | http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/ | POINT (-73.87962300013866 |
| 6 | 2-5 | Boston Rd & E Tremont Ave at NW corner | 1739.0 | http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/ | POINT (-73.88000500027815 |

If I split the 'name' field by "at" and select the first slice I can group all rows at the same 'stop' but how do I then return all rows associated with the 10 closest groups (stops)?

For instance, when I use this query:

```
 select wkb_geometry 
 from osm.subwaypoints s
 where s.line like '%C%'
 order by ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID( ST_Point(  -73.96833020663865,40.68396650310555), 4326),s.wkb_geometry ) LIMIT 10
```

I get the nearest 10 entrances, but it only accounts for 2 actual stops

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is to give a unique name to each 'stop'.
Like you mentioned we can do this if you split the field by 'at', something like:

```
ALTER TABLE osm.subwaypoints 
ADD COLUMN station_na VARCHAR;

UPDATE osm.subwaypoints 
SET station_na = left(name, strpos(name, '_') - 1);
```

Then we go ahead and run the following query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS osm.subwaypoints_nearten;

CREATE TABLE public.subwaypoints_nearten AS
    SELECT a.*
    FROM osm.subwaypoints a
    INNER JOIN 
     (
     SELECT s.station_na
     from osm.subwaypoints s
     where s.line like '%C%'
     GROUP BY station_na
     order by ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID( ST_Point(  -73.96833020663865,40.68396650310555), 4326),ST_COLLECT(s.geom) ) LIMIT 10
     ) as b
    ON a.station_na = b.station_na
    WHERE a.line like '%C%';
```

Here we are using a sub query to, first of all, get a list of all the 'station_na's that are the 10 closest to our point (GROUP BY station_na is doing the work here keep each 'stop' grouped).
Then the outer query is selecting the details of the points that match that list of station names.

Closest 10 '%C%' line stations:[image: Closest 10 '%C%' line stations]

You have a **WHERE** select for line so I've included that above.
The same query without the line filter would be:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS osm.subwaypoints_nearten_notc;

CREATE TABLE osm.subwaypoints_nearten_notc AS
    SELECT a.*
    FROM osm.subwaypoints a
    INNER JOIN 
     (
     SELECT s.station_na
     from osm.subwaypoints s
     GROUP BY station_na
     order by ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID( ST_Point(  -73.96833020663865,40.68396650310555), 4326),ST_COLLECT(s.geom) ) LIMIT 10
     ) as b
    ON a.station_na = b.station_na;
```

Closest 10 stations of any line:[image: Closest 10 stations of any line:]

Comment: Excellent! I wasn't aware of the ST_Collect method for aggregating geometries on a group by. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad it worked!
I should have mentioned 'ST_Collect' in the description.

Comment: For better performance, you could create a table of the stop point groups with a spatial index on the geometry column, and then use the KNN `<->` operator.